# How to get handle to the AngularJS ngHandsontable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

I have a AngularJS project were I have a ngHandsontable defined in the HTML code. I am trying to get a handle to the table in order to attach a 'afterChange' hook to it. How do I get the handle to the table?

Code Example:

HTML

```
<div id="hoTableContainer">
<hot-table id="handsontableId" datarows="myData">
    <hot-column data="name" title="'Name'"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="group" title="'Group'" readOnly></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="unit" title="'Unit'"></hot-column>
</hot-table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('handsontableId').addHook(...)
// Also tried:
var hotInstance = $("#hoTableContainer").handsontable('getInstance');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events you are looking for are:

- [beforeChange](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/Hooks.html#event:beforeChange)
- [afterChange](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/Hooks.html#event:afterChange)

All you have to do is, define a settings object in your controller:

```
$scope.myAfterChangeHandler = function () {
    // your code
};

$scope.mySettings = {
     afterChange: $scope.myAfterChangeHandler
};
```

and then in your HTML, reference that setting object

`<hot-table id="handsontableId" datarows="myData" settings="mySettings">`

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on where I can find what settings are available such as the afterChange setting that you showed me?

Comment: Check the links in the answer. Those link will take you to the documentation. If not go to this URL 'http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/tutorial-quick-start.html' and use the search box to find what you want

Comment: I have realized that I probably still need the handle to the table as I need to use the handsontable updateSettings method to apply readOnly=true to some specific cells. I have tried to use var hotInstance = $("#hoTableContainer").handsontable('getInstance'); but it only results in undefined. Got any suggestions?

Comment: `var hotInstance = $("#example1").handsontable('getInstance');` << This should help you. source: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/demo-jquery.html